# Inverse function of product of exponential matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, noncommutative-algebra

I am looking for the value of $\mathbf{X}$ in a function of the type

\begin{align}
   (\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{A})e^{\mathbf{X}}e^{-\mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{B}
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{A}$,$\mathbf{B}$,$\mathbf{X}\in \Re^{n\times n}$. I assume that $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ do not commute, i.e., $\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{X} \neq \mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{X}$ which means that $e^{\mathbf{X}}e^{-\mathbf{A}} \neq e^{\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{A}}$. This problem is similar to the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) but in a more generic setting.

I am trying to find an analytical solution which gives all the infinite possible values in a similar manner to the Lambert W function.

Does anyone know if this problem has been solved or has any hint on how to approach it?